# Killing a thread in python - simple program does not seem to work

Tags: python, multithreading

The following simple python program does not seem to work. It is a simplification of the recipe mentioned in http://code.activestate.com/recipes/496960-thread2-killable-threads/

It spawns off a separate thread with an infinite for-loop, and tries to kill it.

The PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc returns a 0, which is supposed to be "invalid threadId", and hence the spawned thread does not get killed. What am I missing?

```
import threading
from threading import Thread
import time

def runThread():
    def f():
        while(1):
            pass
    thr = Thread(target=f, args=[])
    thr.start()
    for tid, tobj in threading._active.items():
        if tobj == thr:
            return (tid, tobj)
    return (-1, None)

import ctypes

def main():
    (tid, thr) = runThread()
    time.sleep(5)
    print "ThreadId is ", thr.ident
    res = ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(thr.ident,   ctypes.py_object(Exception("Hello world")))
    print res
    time.sleep(2)
    print "Threads are ", str(threading._active)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: `PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc` expects the first argument to be of type long, i.e. `ctypes.c_long(thr.ident)`

Comment: This works. Thanks.